# Folding in Vim latex-suite

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I have installed and configured vim latex-suite successfully.
However whenever i try to type ":\rf" in normal mode i get an error "E10 : \ should be followed by /,? or &" .
Could anyone tell me what i am missing here ? 
I am following this [beginners guide](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-folding.html) .

Answer (score 3):

Ok! 
That was indeed an awkward question!
I did not know that typing "\rf" "In normal mode, in Vim" means just typing ":normal \rf" in the Escape mode, and not only "\rf" or ": \rf".
This what happens when learning vim-latex suite before fully understanding Vim.

Comment: Or just type `\rf` in the normal mode (i.e., do not precede it with `:`)